# Delete character

Tags: javascript, masking

Please help me make a mask to fill in the web address.
I have a function in which while filling the name of the store, the web address is automatically selected. But some of the first letters in this case are getting deleted. Here is the mask itself

```
 v-mask="{
          mask: 'jujuw\\ay.com/*{4,20}',
          definitions: {
            '*': {
              validator: '[0-9A-Za-z\-]',
              casing: 'lower'
            }
          }
        }"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve